# Does Mesos really treat all your resources as a single pool?

Tags: mesos

Mesos is advertised as a system that lets you program against your datacenter like it's a single pool of resources (See the [Mesos Website](http://mesos.apache.org/)). But is this really true that you don't need to consider the configuration of the individual machines? Using Mesos, can you request more resources for a task than are available on a single machine?

For example, if you have 10 machines each with 2 cores and 2g of RAM and 20g HD, can you really request 10 cores, 15g of RAM and 100g of disk space for a single task?

- If so, how does this work? Is Mesos able to address memory across machines for you, and use other CPUs as local threads and create a single filesystem from a number of distributed nodes?
- How does it accomplish this without suffering from the [Fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing), especially those related to network latency and transport cost?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to this [Mesos architecture](http://mesos.apache.org/documentation/latest/architecture/#mesos-architecture) you can't aggregate resources from different slaves (agents / machines) to use them for one task.

As you can see there is strict "taks per agent" situation
[image: Architecture]

Also their example says pretty much same

> Let’s walk through the events in the figure.
>
> Agent 1 reports to the master that it has 4 CPUs and 4 GB of memory
>   free. The master then invokes the allocation policy module, which
>   tells it that framework 1 should be offered all available resources.
>   The master sends a resource offer describing what is available on
>   agent 1 to framework 1. The framework’s scheduler replies to the
>   master with information about two tasks to run on the agent, using <2
>   CPUs, 1 GB RAM> for the first task, and <1 CPUs, 2 GB RAM> for the
>   second task. Finally, the master sends the tasks to the agent, which
>   allocates appropriate resources to the framework’s executor, which in
>   turn launches the two tasks (depicted with dotted-line borders in the
>   figure). Because 1 CPU and 1 GB of RAM are still unallocated, the
>   allocation module may now offer them to framework 2.